# How to Specify DNS Server for Test-Connection and Test-NetConnection in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Specify DNS-Server for `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection`

Is there any way to specify DNS Server for powershell `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection` cmdlets to use in a script?
For example `Resolve-DnsName` cmdlet has this feature with `-server` parameter but these don't, is ther any workaround?
By default they use System default DNS.

Comment: If you can’t find any better option, a workaround might be to resolve the host name with ```Resolve-DnsName``` using your specific dns server and then ```Test-NetConnection``` with the resolved IP address…

Comment: If powershell doesnt have it is because .net doesnt have and not even ping from cmd has a way to specify a dns server afaik

Comment: @mclayton The problem with this is when testing TCP connection to domains behind a CDN, if you resolve the IP address you will get CDN IP, thus testing TCP connection to CDN not actual website.

Answer (score 0):

You can either resolve the name first or temporarily change the computer's DNS settings. (The second is a very bad idea in most cases)

To get the IP adress use something like this:

```
$ipAddress = Resolve-DnsName -Name <WantedHost> -Server <WantedDNS> | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress

if ($ipAddress) { ... your tests ... }
```

Comment: The problem with this is when testing TCP connection to domains behind a CDN, if you resolve the IP address you will get CDN IP, thus testing TCP connection to CDN not actual website.

Comment: @Empirical4650 then you need a DNS server which has the real ip adresses. This can't be solved on the client you use for the testing.